# Select records and order by scores desc

Tags: mysql, sql

From the following data, how can I select all the children a parent has ordered by the perCent desc of those children?

Parents are type 3 only.

I tried the below, but that orders the entire result set. I need to order by each parents childrens perCent. You'll see in the expected results:

```
select b.id, b.type, b.perCent from scores a 
INNER JOIN scores b on a.id = b.parent and a.type=3 order by b.perCent desc;
```

**Main Table**

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "country"   "votes" "perCent"
"24"    "1"     "1"         "US"        "30"    "0"
"25"    "3"     "24"        "US"        "30"    "0"
"26"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "15"    "50.00"
"27"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "10"    "33.33"
"28"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "5"     "16.66"

"29"    "1"     "1"         "US"        "50"    "0"
"30"    "3"     "29"        "US"        "50"    "0"
"31"    "10"    "29"        "US"        "20"    "40.00"
"32"    "10"    "29"        "US"        "15"    "25.00"
"33"    "10"    "29"        "US"        "15"    "35.00"
```

**Expected results:**

```
"id"    "perCent" //Ordered by each parents childrens perCent desc
"26"    "50.00"
"27"    "33.33"
"28"    "16.66"

"31"    "40.00"
"33"    "35.00"
"32"    "25.00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the same general join, but apply an order by across multiple columns:

```
select child.id as childId, child.perCent
from scores parent
join scores child
   on parent.id = child.parent
where parent.type = 3
order by parent.id, child.perCent desc
```

This says, first order by the parent (such that all children for the parent will appear together) and then order by each child's (per said parent) percent descending.

Note that even though the `parent.id` column wasn't selected, it is still eligible for ordering.

Comment: Parents are type 3. This is only between type 3 and their children.

Comment: mysql does not support the `OVER` clause.

Comment: Your second solution is what I was looking for. I'm testing it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,perCent from scores 
where parent in (select id from scores where type=3)
order by parent, percent desc
```

Comment: If I change the scores, the id appear ordered, but the scores will not

Comment: The id's need not be ordered. Only the scores. See my desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(id),GROUP_CONCAT(type),GROUP_CONCAT(parent) from atab where type = 10 group by parent  order by id
```

Here you will get comma separated values sorted by id
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5976d/2)

Comment: err, this has nothing to do with the question asked.  maybe you posted this answer on the wrong question?